# Greplin Programming Challenge Level 3 (Matlab)

Tags: javascript, math, matlab

In Greplin challenge level 3 it is required to count the number of subsets which sum up to another element in list. See [Greplin](http://challenge.greplin.com/) and [Challenge Description and Python code](https://github.com/krsanky/greplin-challenge/blob/master/level3.py).
I also found [this code in javascript](http://dmitrionsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/10/greplin-challenge-3-in-javascript_21.html), but I found it far less understoodable than Python.

My question is if there's some kind of Matlab command for finding all subsets of array, in similar way to the combinations library in python?
Reffering to the challenge in your answer will be appreciated.

I tried some kind of writing my own code to it, but it obviously didn't work so well.

```
Nums = [3   4   9   14  15  19  28  37  47  50  54  56  59  61  70  73  78  81  92  95  97  99];
% Nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];

SubsetCount = 0;
for Ind = 1:length(Nums)

    maxNum = Nums(Ind);
    s = setdiff( Nums, maxNum );
    NumSubsetsCountToIt = NumSubsetsCount( s,  maxNum);
    SubsetCount = SubsetCount + NumSubsetsCountToIt;

end
disp(SubsetCount);

function    NumSubsetsCountToIt = NumSubsetsCount( Nums, SumUpNum )
global OptionsToGetTo

NumSubsetsCountToIt = 0;
validNums = Nums;

if sum(validNums)==SumUpNum

    NumSubsetsCountToIt = 1;

else

    for Ind=length( validNums ):-1:1
        outNum = validNums(Ind);
        s = setdiff(validNums, outNum );
        NumSubsets = NumSubsetsCount( s, SumUpNum-outNum );
        NumSubsetsCountToIt = NumSubsetsCountToIt+NumSubsets;
    end
    NumSubsetsCountToIt = floor((NumSubsetsCountToIt+1)/2);

end

OptionsToGetTo(2, b) = NumSubsetsCountToIt;
```

Comment: Ok, more interesting is to code golf this problem. If N = [3, 4, 9, 14, 15, 19, 28, 37, 47, 50, 54, 56, 59, 61, 70, 73, 78, 81, 92, 95, 97, 99]; Then how many characters can you solve the problem in? My solution was 54 characters. Use only standard MATLAB functions.

Comment: My fastest solution so far in matlab took .6 seconds, the code golf solution was 2.29 seconds.

Comment: to @woodchips: .6 seconds is extremely fast.. Using the combnk function below is taking over 30 seconds for me. Could you post your fast and golf code solution?

Comment: But then I'm giving away the answer to the challenge. I'll give you a hint though. The code golf solution (now @ 52 characters) uses dec2bin(1:2^21-1). A matrix multiply gives you various sums of subsets. Would ismember help? Then you must subtract off the 21 possible singlet solutions. The (fast) alternative solution uses my code to generate the partitions of an integer as the sum of a set of other numbers. It is on the FEX. Merely count the number of solutions found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`combnk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/combnk.html) to find all possible combinations of `n` items taken `k` at a time. Using the competition's example:

```
values=[1,2,3,4,6];%# test vector
values=sort(values(:),'ascend');%#not needed here, but good to sort as indexing becomes easier in the end.
matchingSubsets=cell(numel(values)-1,1);%we don't need the trivial case of j=j. So, 1 less cell.

for i=2:numel(values)
    combinations=combnk(values,i);
    matchingSubsets{i-1}=combinations(sum(combinations(:,1:i-1),2)==combinations(:,i),:);%# this is where the sorting helps, as you now know that the last column is the max value.
end
```

The result:

```
matchingSubsets{:}
ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-2

ans =
     2     4     6
     1     3     4
     1     2     3

ans =
     1     2     3     6

ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-5
```

To get the final answer, i.e., the number of subsets,

```
subsetSizes=cell2mat(cellfun(@size,matchingSubsets,'UniformOutput',false));
totalSubsets=sum(subsetSizes(:,1));
```

which gives `totalSubsets=4`.